# jQuery toArray function and how to use its elements

Tags: jquery

I wrote this code, which is a rating system.
What I want to happen is when you hover over a star, the stars before it should trigger.

A picture change happens whenever I hover over a star, but the stars before it dont change.

```
             $('.star').hover(function(){

            $(this).children().attr('src','StarsRating/star_yellow.png'); 

            var count=$(this).attr('data-count');
            var starArray =$('.star').toArray();


            for(i=0; i<count; i++){
                //The problem is here. the attributes of the stars should change to star_yellow.png..but they dont
```

console.log(starArray[i]);
                    $(starArray[i]).attr('src','StarsRating/star_yellow.png');
                }

```
         },function(){
            $(this).children().attr('src','StarsRating/star_grey.png'); 
         });
```

Html:

```
        <div id="ratingStars">
        <div class="star" data-count="1">
            <img src="StarsRating/star_yellow.png"/>
        </div>
         <div class="star" data-count="2">
             <img src="StarsRating/star_grey.png"/>
        </div>
         <div class="star" data-count="3">
            <img src="StarsRating/star_grey.png"/>
        </div>
         <div class="star" data-count="4">
            <img src="StarsRating/star_grey.png"/>
        </div>
         <div class="star" data-count="5">
            <img src="StarsRating/star_grey.png"/>
        </div>
```

UPDATE THAT IS WHAT I GET WHEN I PUT THE CONSOLE INSIDE THE LOOP:

```
   <div class=​"star" data-count=​"1" src=​"StarsRating/​star_yellow.png">​…​</div>​
newEmptyPHPWebPage.php:41
<div class=​"star" data-count=​"2" src=​"StarsRating/​star_yellow.png">​…​</div>​
newEmptyPHPWebPage.php:41
<div class=​"star" data-count=​"3" src=​"StarsRating/​star_yellow.png">​…​</div>
```

But why I can see that it switched on teh console, but not on the document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats the answer:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
         $('.star').hover(function(){
            $(this).children().attr('src','StarsRating/star_yellow.png'); 
            var count=$(this).attr('data-count');
            **var starArray =$('.star').children().toArray();**

            for(i=0; i<count; i++){

                var current= $(starArray[i]);
               current.attr('src','StarsRating/star_yellow.png');
            }

         },function(){
             $('.star img').attr('src','StarsRating/star_grey.png');


         });
    </script>
```

var starArray =$('.star').toArray(); <--I got the divs

var starArray =$('.star').children().toArray();<-- Now I got the images

Answer (score 2):

If you want to highlight all stars up to and including the star being hovered over, an array and a loop isn't necessary if you use the `.prevAll` function.

Try:

```
$('.star').hover(function() {
    var star = $(this);
    star.add(star.prevAll('.star')).find('img').attr('src','StarsRating/star_yellow.png');
},function() {
    $(this).parent().children('.star').find('img').attr('src','StarsRating/star_grey.png');
});
```

The first function finds all previous siblings of the hovered star and turns them (as well as the hovered star) yellow. The second function finds all children stars of the container element and turns them grey again.

Comment: Yes? Are you referring to setting the `src` of the images and not the div containers? My solution does the same (`.find('img')`). It also avoids the need to create a for loop, as the functionality you're trying to implement is handled nicely by the `.prevAll` function.

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with you're logic. Inside you're hover function you get the children of a star object, but what you really want is the children of the parent of the star object :)

You have:

```
$(this).children().attr('src','StarsRating/star_yellow.png');
```

May work:

```
$(this).parent().children().attr('src', 'StarsRating/star_yellow.png');
```

Thanks to comment from jackwanders: 
.children() finds elements that are hierarchically below the target element in the DOM, not simply those elements which appear after it in source code. The star element you hover over has no children. It does have siblings, however, so $(this).siblings('.star') would work, as would $(this).parent().children('.star')

And also this had to be changed:

```
 var starArray = $('.star').toArray();
```

to

```
$('.star').children().toArray();
```

Also; instead of:

```
        for(i=0; i<count; i++){
            //The problem is here. the attributes of the stars should change to star_yellow.png..but they dont
            $(starArray[i]).attr('src','StarsRating/star_yellow.png');
        }
```

Try the jquery .each function: http://api.jquery.com/each/

```
$("#ratingStars").each(function(index) {

    if( index >= count ) 
        return false; // break

    $(this).attr('src', 'StarsRating/star_yellow.png');


});
```

Comment: i really, dont think it matters

Comment: You're code has a logic error as you select the children of a star, not the container with the stars. I've updated my answer

Comment: Yes, it does. `.children()` finds elements that are hierarchically below the target element in the DOM, not simply those elements which appear after it in source code. The star element you hover over has no children. It does have siblings, however, so `$(this).siblings('.star')` would work, as would `$(this).parent().children('.star')`

Comment: That was close, but wrong. What I had to do is to change the toArray line to this: var starArray =$('.star').children().toArray();.. that means instead of getting the divs, I will be getting the images

Comment: Thank you for that jackwanders. I will update the answer to reflect you're insight.

Comment: Good to hear that you fixed it :)